# The Razor and the strange Html.Raw encoding in an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I use ASP.NET Framework (v4.5.1).

The following line in a razor view

```
<iframe 
data-mytest="@Html.Raw(greetingLink)" 
        src="@Html.Raw(greetingLink)" width="430" height="300" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" title="video youtube"></iframe>
```

gives the following result in the code source of the generated page:

```
<iframe  
data-mytest="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gVIFEVLzP4o?autoplay=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&rel=0" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gVIFEVLzP4o?autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;rel=0" width="430" height="300" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" title="video youtube"></iframe>
```

If you observe, the second url is URL encoded(`&`=>`&amp;`). What could produce such a behavior, that the same `@Html.Raw(greetingLink)` code produce once non-encoded, and the second time the encoded string?

Comment: Razor parses the markup and interprets certain known attributes instead of just doing basic text replacement. What do you get if you use `@greetingLink` instead?

Comment: if I put `data-mytest="@greetingLink"` I get `data-mytest="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gVIFEVLzP4o?autoplay=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;controls=0&amp;rel=0"`

Comment: That's good. Now both attributes have valid markup.

Comment: you mean, both invalid one? I need `&` and not `&amp;`

Comment: No. In an attribute, the `&` character has to be encoded as `&amp;`.  A bare `&` like you're trying to do is not valid markup.

Comment: but this is not a simple attribute, this is a link, I need the raw one

Comment: If you read the value in code, the character will be what you want it to be.

Comment: I don't read the value in code, this is the youtube video embeding, please see an exampe here https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en

Comment: I'm gobsmacked. That document shows invalid markup.  Nevertheless, it will work with correct markup (`&amp;`) and you don't have to worry about whether or not a browser will let you get away with a syntax error.

Comment: ok, man, I would like to trust you, but I'd rather trust to the Google documentation, as this is the YouTube owner itself. Please study this question more.